# Apparent Net7 dll Differences using Blazor Wasm with Shared Netstandard Libraries

Tags: visual-studio, grpc, blazor-webassembly, .net-standard, .net-7.0

Good Afternoon,

I apologize for the title if it is weird, as I don't really know how to describe this.
To describe my project:

- Project has been fine for months
- Blazor Wasm project, using Identity Server
- Separate Identity grpc service for authenticating logins (hit by Server project piece of the mentioned wasm project)
- Both grpc service and wasm use shared organizational nuget packages for identity objects (netstandard libraries)
- Key Piece: There are protobuf.net metatype setups for the MSFT dlls that are serialized within Grpc service. E.g. as we cannot set the protomembers for these classes (ClaimsIdentity is one of them, at is the focus of this issue) The metatype setup is to expose the necessary properties to both client and service...
- Recently, wasm was updated to net7
- When deployed, the metatype setup for ClaimsIdentity blows up, stating that the field "Label" cannot be found. App doesn't run, fails within Program.cs...makes sense...so far...

Now, first thing I did was switch to the dev branch, pull latest, etc. Run locally, don't get the same issue; no issue at all actually, ran without any problems. Do "Go To Definition" and see the Label field within the ClaimsIdentity class (netstandard).

After updating VS, rebuilding, etc... I push out a pacifier release so people can test (removed the ClaimsIdentity line as the wasm piece doesn't need it, we're just reusing a helper method that had it in there). I then go back and try the Go To Definition stuff again, this time, I'm directed to the 7.0.0.0 dll of System.Security.Claims. The class is definitely different than the netstandard one (why I'm now sent to this definition, I dunno, I suspect caching of code/dll I dunno, whatever). Still, I cannot duplicate the issue when debugging.

At this point, after seeing that I'm getting different files on my own machine. I decided to use ILSpy and see if the deployed System.Security.Claims dll is the same....it is not. It is also System.Security.Claims v7.0.0.0, but only has a _label, private property.

Easy fix is just to remove the line throwing causing the issue, but, that is superficial. I'd like to know what I'm missing in why I'm seeing different contents between net 7 dlls. I'm thinking I'm overlooking something dumb, actually, I hope that I am.

Image: Left is Locally Built, Right is what gets deployed (both being Azure Devops and manual publish)

[image: Left is Locally Built, Right is what gets deployed (both being Azure Devops and manual publish)]